# Seqindignot sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, integer

*Title is made up, from 'Sequence Index Digit Not'.*

### Challenge:

Given an integer `n` which is `>= 0`, output the `n`'th number of the following sequence.
Here are the first 50 items, with it's (0-indexed) index above it:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6 9 8 22 20 30 24 23 26 25 28 27 32 11 33 10 14 13 16 15 18 17 31 12 29 19 21 50 40 41 42 44 45 35 36 37 51 38 39 52 53 55 56 34
```

### How does this sequence work?

The number at index `n` must be the first in order that does not have any digits in common with `n`, and hasn't occurred yet for previous indexes. So when we look at normal sequence like this from `0-60`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

We define the `n`'th values like this:

- `0`: The first number (`0`) contains the same digit, so we look for the next (`1`), which does not contain the same digit. So `n=0` outputs `1`.
- `1`: The first number (`0`) does not contain the same digit, so `n=1` outputs `0`.
- `2`: We've already encountered `0` and `1`, and the next digit (`2`) contains the same digit, so we look for the next (`3`), which does not contain the same digit. So `n=2` outputs `3`.
- ...
- `10`: We've already encountered `0-9`, so the next in line is `10`. `10-19` contain the matching digit `1`, `20` contains the matching digit `0`, `21` contains the matching digit `1` again, `22` is valid, so `n=10` outputs `22`.
- etc.

### Challenge rules:

- If your language is 1-indexed (or you choose to) you are allowed to start the sequence at `3 2 5 4 7 ...` (skipping the `1` at `n=0` and the `0` at `n=1`).
- The minimum largest index you should support is `25,000`. *NOTE: The sequence stops at index `1,023,456,788`, because the next index in line contains all 10 digits.*
- You are also allowed to output / return an array/list of the entire sequence up to and including index `n` if you want to.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

*This sequence actually created pairs regarding index and outputs. If index `n` outputs `o`, index `o` outputs `n`.* So you can input either the left or right, and the output will be the other side:

```
0      <->  1       (this test case is optional)
2      <->  3
10     <->  22
12     <->  30
34     <->  50
89     <->  100
111    <->  200
112    <->  300
199    <->  322
2231   <->  4456
9605   <->  11118
19235  <->  46000
23451  <->  60668
25000  <->  13674
```

[Here is a pastebin of the first 25,001 test cases if you want to try others.](https://pastebin.com/FEL5jm4n)

Comment: [Related, but not a dupe.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138423/smallest-unseen-but-no-sharing-digits)

Comment: As with the related challenge, [the scatterplot is quite fun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJXz4.png). :)

Comment: @MartinEnder When I saw the scatterplot of the related challenge, I indeed figured this one would be similar. Turns out it indeed is rather similar, but still different. :)

Comment: How come such an important sequence is not on OEIS?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Good question. Actually, I think [all my sequence-challenges so far](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a52210%20%5bsequence%5d%20views%3a1) weren't in OEIS (yet) when I posted them. ;)

Comment: My answer will stack overflow `n > 71`. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Neil Sorry, but "_The minimum largest index you should support is `25,000`._" I don't mind slightly lower (like > 5k), but 71 is a bit too low. I'm afraid you'll have to find a different approach.. :(

Comment: Either that or find an interpreter that supports tail recursion...

Comment: I don't get the "1-based index" option, wouldn't the sequence go `[2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,20,30,22,23,...]`? (i.e. index starting at `1` and each term is the first with no colliding digits and not yet used `>=1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
u+Gf!|}TG@`H`T0hQY
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eu%2BGf%21%7C%7DTG%40%60H%60T0hQY&input=89&test_suite_input=0%0A2%0A10%0A12%0A34%0A89%0A111&debug=0)** or **[Check more test cases!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eu%2BGf%21%7C%7DTG%40%60H%60T0hQY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A2%0A10%0A12%0A34%0A89%0A111&debug=0)**

Note that this returns the entire sequence up to index **N**, but the link returns the last number only, by prepending an `e` (end). If you want to see the raw value returned by this program, [just remove it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf%21%7C%7DTG%40%60H%60T0hQY&input=12&test_suite_input=0%0A2%0A10%0A12%0A34%0A89%0A111&debug=0).

### How it works

```
u+Gf!|}TG@`H`T0hQY  - Full program.

u     ...      hQY  - Reduce hQ (the input incremented) from left to right, with the
                       function ...(G, H), with starting value Y (the empty list).
                       G is the current value and H is the iteration index.
   f          0     - First integer starting from 0, that satisfies the following:
      }TG             - Appears in G...
     |   @`H`T        - Or its (string) intersection with the current index (H) is
                        non-empty.
    !                 - Logical NOT (boolean negation).
 +G                 - Append the value obtained above to the current value (G).
                      This becomes the given value for the next iteration.
                    - Implicitly print all intermediate results, or add e to print 
                      the last one.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>92</s> <s>91</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes

```python
a=()
i=0
exec"x=0\nwhile set(`x`)&set(`i`)or x in a:x+=1\na+=x,;i+=1;"*-~input()
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw7CoAwDADQ3VMEB2n9QHVUchOHFik0ILFoxbh49Spub3rxTmHjIWeHSheEpvDil1LQzHwFWj0cPikrVlc/yOptBwFicKM02M/sGpR2os9TWXcPcTzTd8WdOIHLuTcv)

Prints a list of the first `n+1` numbers

---

Different approach, which is a lot faster:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 96 bytes

```python
n=input()
r=range(9*n)
i=0
exec"x=0\nwhile set(`r[x]`)&set(`i`):x+=1\nprint r.pop(x),;i+=1;"*-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchLCsJADADQ/ZyidCGT@mHqTktO0gojEmxA0hBHGjdefRR3j6fvMi9yrFWQRV8lQjC0q9wpnjqBwJgCOd1axzTJOvODmieVmG30S4bN35zh7FvsJ1FjKY0ddNHosBv4t0Pb7T9Sa59S@gI)

Comment: [88 bytes using a tuple](https://tio.run/##HcyxCoAgEADQva84GkLTwBoL/6RBCcGDuKSMrqVft2h700t3jhsNpaD21mghq8Bhqdmama6Ia4AjZOHYyeYHOrntwIAEfmRl@5m8sqwn/DzVbfcgpTN/T9qRMvhSevMC)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>80</s> 69 bytes

```
f n=[x|x<-[0..],all(`notElem`show n)$show x,all(/=x)$f<$>[0..n-1]]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcq9CoAgFEDhV7mCQ0H/c7b1FCHooBRdr1JCDr27kdMZzrfr@zSIOVsgsaU3ze02dJ1sNGKlyMcVjVP37h@gmpem8nqRam5nvvyc2lFKxobs9EEgIFwHReDgdAALvxgnmT8)

Very slow for large `n`.

```
f n=
    [x|x<-[0..]     ] !!0          -- pick the first of all 'x' from [0..]
                                   -- where
      all(`notElem`show n)$show x  -- no digit of 'n' appears in 'x', and
      all(/=x)                     -- 'x' is not seen before, i.e. not in the list
               f<$>[0..n-1]        -- 'f' mapped to [0..n-1]
```

Edit: @Laikoni saved 10 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Computing the nth term directly instead of indexing into the sequence is shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvNCoJAGEX3PcUJXBSkzPc5/oG26ylCyEVSNE6RQi56d5siuHAv53Av3Xg7O7csPb45zu@5jo8mSdqdv08Hdx6Yo76O9l/mY2l3nXOb09@dxsv9hd9Gv57b9dosQ3f1NDyeVz8RMXQPer5vMe0qjhEMKUqGpSCnokQVDdSgFg0yRzM08IJUESFNEYNYJIwcyZASCVaQ8K2QChUygw0RrGItywc "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>218</s> <s>217</s> <s>213</s> <s>210</s> <s>202</s> <s>200</s> <s>172</s> <s>171</s> <s>170</s> <s>168</s> 167 bytes

I cannot believe that I didn't just return `k` all this time...

```java
i->{int j=-1,k=0,y=1;for(String r=" ",e=r;j++<i;r+=~-k+e,y=1)for(k=0;y>0;k++)for(int f:(k+(y=0)+"").getBytes())y+=(e+j).indexOf(f)<0&!r.contains(e+k+e)?0:1;return~-k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9NT4UwELy/X1E5mNZCA9dXiokHEw/GA0fjoUIh5aPFsrzYEPzrWAwHb7uzMzsznbzJxE7KdHW/63GyDlAXMLaAHlizmAq0NeyBX6blc9AVqgY5z@hVaoPWywwSAvZ80vIXA6pVLkbnUKBSfWlT69ZYQGLXSbFqExxEksW9SGMvMt5Yh0tw2rTIiQhFsRKOd5TmmjsqfpKeqoNHDl7QcF@kvKf0bz@eNVfcU@xFSmgUEdYqePKgZkyIpwIr2hEWIqjvtwY3JE/v7xyrrIHQYA7X8J08pteMOwWLM8GObzs/y579blbXaAyCM@f7hyRr6WdQI7MLsCmAgP9VZXKaBo@zlBC@bfsv)

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a different approach then I was using when I made the pastebin with my Java program. And it seems you can golf `for(char f:(""+k).toCharArray())` to `for(int f:(""+k).getBytes())`, `r.substring(-~r.trim().lastIndexOf(32));` and to `r.substring(r.lastIndexOf(32)-1)`.

Comment: Must be trimmed before lastIndexOf as there's a space on the end

Comment: Ah, I indeed made a mistake.. I knew the String contained both a leading and trailing space, but my incorrectly suggested change only works for the first 10 single-digit numbers.. My bad

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 39 bytes

```apl
0∘{0=⍵:1⋄(~⍺∊0∇¨⍳⍵)∧⊃∧/≠/⍕¨⍺⍵:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1}
```

Uses `⎕IO←0`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9NA5KOOGdUGto96t1oZPupu0ah71LvrUUcXULj90IpHvZuBEpqPOpY/6moGkvqPOhfoP@qdCpLZBdICorpbgCyg8ke9IFFtw9r//9PAWg0NAQ)

**How?**

Recursion.

`0=⍵:1` - take a guess.

`~⍺∊0∇¨⍳⍵` - left arg (accumulator) is not already in previous results

`∧⊃∧/≠/⍕¨⍺⍵` - and the string representation of the accumulator and `n` are different

`:⍺` - then return the accumulator.

`⍵∇⍨⍺+1` - otherwise, increment accumulator and recurse.

Comment: Wow.. I know the default rule is "given any amount of memory and time", but your code already times out for `n=10` in TIO.. :S That must be a very performance-heavy operation you're doing there. Is it the recursion that causes this, or is something else the bottleneck?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the second condition basically apply the function on the range of 0..n-1, and considering the same apply for every call, that would come roughly at a huge O(2^n). of course it would be lower with a more reasonable code, but that's where the bottleneck sits

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 92 bytes

```python
o=1,
for i in range(int(input())):
 x=0
 while{*str(x),x}&{*str(~i),*o}:x+=1
 o+=x,
print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9CoUwDEDhPU@RSRrtYHET@jAO/gSkKbWXGxF99ao4HPimE/e8SOhKEe8sTJKQkQOmIcyj4ZCf4i8bIuoB1beA/4XX8ai3nIyS1bP6fDHZWs5eG@8ApfFqIab3IFSKa28)

This prints all the terms up to the **N**th one. Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for  <s>-4</s>  -5 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>103 88</s> 81

**Edit** Revised including *many* clever ideas by @Neil

```js
n=>eval("for(r=[j=i=0];i<=n;)j=r[j]||(i+'').match(`[${j}]`)?j+1:!(r[k=j]=++i);k")
```

*Starting point*

Basic idea: a loop from 0 to n, and an inner loop checking values still not used

```js
n=>{
  var r=[]
  for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
  {
    s=new Set(i+'')
    for(j=-1;s;)
    {
      if (!r[++j] && ![...j+''].some(d=>s.has(d)))
      {
        r[j]=1
        console.log(i,j)
        s=0
      }
    }
  }
  return j
}
```

*Current version more readable*

```js
n=>{
  for(r = [j=i=0]; i <= n; )
    if (r[j] || (i+'').match(`[${j}]`))
      ++j
    else
      r [k=j] = ++i,
      j = 0;
  return k
}
```

**Test**

```js
var f=
n=>eval("for(r=[j=i=0];i<=n;)j=r[j]||(i+'').match(`[${j}]`)?j+1:!(r[k=j]=++i);k")

update=_=>{
  var i=+I.value
  if (i < 1e4 || confirm("Really?")) {
    O.textContent=i + ' -> ...'
    setTimeout(_=>O.textContent=i + ' -> ' + f(i), 100)
  }
}  

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value=100 type=number max=1023456788>
<button onclick='update()'>Go</button>
(slow when input > 1000)
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Would replacing `~s.search(d)` with `s.match(d)` work?

Comment: I think you can save another byte by changing `0` to `j++`, removing the `++` from the `j` it was on before and then starting `j` from `0` instead of `-1`.

Comment: I think I was able to switch to a single loop: `n=>eval("for(r=[j=i='0'];i<=n;)r[j]|[...''+j].some(d=>i.match(d))?j++:(i=++i+'',r[k=j]=1,j=0);k")`

Comment: @Neil a single loop would be wonderful

Comment: @Neil the single loop is great, thanks

Comment: Oh, you took my `match` idea and ran with it, very nice!

Comment: I think ``n=>eval("for(r=[],j=i='0';i<=n;)j=r[j]||i.match(`[${j}]`)?++j:!(i=r[k=j]=++i+'');k")`` saves another byte though.

Comment: @Neil thanks again, found a way to save 7

Comment: Oh, well if you're going to use numeric values for `r[]` then you can switch from `||` to `|` right?

Comment: @Neil problems with the return value from match that is an array (sorry can't go in chat from here)

Comment: Oh, I forgot I changed it already ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>217</s> 205 bytes

```go
package g;import("fmt";"strconv";"strings");var(
d=make(map[int]int)
a=strconv.Itoa)
func G(L int){k,i:=0,0;for;i<=L;i++{s:=a(i);k=0;for d[k]>0||strings.ContainsAny(a(k),s){k++;}
d[k]=1;}
fmt.Print(a(k));}
```

Alternate version (program instead of a package): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@9qsMwDEb3PEXJZJMQnDW6vhA6XejQPYQi0iYIYyvYvoXS9tld94cOggM6@iQtnNKKk8HltLFIDsiu7KMoZxtLKEP0E7vzm8gtIROHUsIZvSiO2qI5CYvrQC6OuWSB@jPT/EVGWcz/bnolC3k1NXVa1Qp29aH7en1kEhya3i9haEcJM3ugH70Dqqpr6DQKkmC0ejY2x8GMv@p2@9zTbNnFnB56dxEojKxD3lNVcC@epm4z5FeafbbjS5BwTym1SqkH)

Improvements:

- removed space after outer `for` by using multiple assignment for `i,k`
- importing `"fmt";` + `fmt.Print` is shorter than `os.Stdout.WriteString` (holdover from `package main` when os.Args was needed)

Comment: Nice, your answer is the first that doesn't time out after 1 minute when I try the `25000` test case. :) So not only a valid solution, but with relatively good performance as well. +1 from me! (PS: In your TIO-link it's the argument you use, input can be removed / is not used.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 114 bytes

```matlab
N=input("");o=[1];for i=1:N;j=0;while(any(o==j)||nnz(ismember(int2str(i),int2str(j))));j++;end;o=[o,j];end;[0:N;o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsIwDAC/gjolaoe0bFj@Qj9QZSjFCFvURm0Agfr3EJC45W46m9L4oJx7ZL3dk6sqD4ZDG@Fsy46xPfQgGOB54Su5UV/OEMVvm@rb8TrTfKTFsaZuTcW@@af4AkhdA@npu7RG4q@HUJ4Wc96HDw)

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) and [Dlosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc) for the character comparison golfing.

### Ungolfed

```matlab
N=input("");o=[1];

for i=1:N;
    j=0;
    while(any(o==j)||nnz(ismember(int2str(i),int2str(j))));
        j++;
    end;
    o=[o,j];
end;
[0:N;o]
```

Basic explanation:

- Outer loop and inner loop, one for index `i`, and another for value to add `j`
- For each `i`, continue to increment `j` if either of the following are met:

  1. Any `j` has been used before
  2. This one gets fun. First, split each numeric value into a vector of digits (e.g., `10` becomes `[1 0]`) using `int2str`. 
     Then, compare the two numbers using `ismember`(e.g., `[1 0]` and `[2 1]` would return `[1 0]`) and then `nnz` to see if any columns matched.
- If none of the above are met, you have the next number! Append to `o`, the output matrix
- Print original indices with output matrix

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me. And seems @DLosc is right, it works even without both `-'0'`. But if there is some edge case we both haven't thought of, `-48` would be a shorter alternative. Also, both `sprintf('%d',...)` can be `int2str(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 bytes

**59 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
$_="@{[0..($;=++$_)*9]}";$_=eval's/\b[^ $-]+ //;$-++;$&;'x$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY3dSsNAGAXv5ylKWawa0uz3s9ksS8D3qLVU6IUQbLAigvjqxtyeYebMl48pLaEdY13Cadw@/Rzifn8f6tg04fTwWI6/27qCy9d52t2659fDyya0x2bTdTW0TVPDXd19h2WJCIrhJHoyAwVZR0EUMcSRhPRIRgakoBFdHUUNdTShPZrRAS1YxARbk4Y5lrAey9iAFTzigiu@Pjqe8B7P@IAXUuTvOn@@Xd9vSztP/w) (Includes `-l` for visual purposes and `$-=0;` to reset each iteration)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 30 bytes

29 bytes of code, +1 for `-p` flag.

```
Fn,a+1{Y0WyNl|_NyMSn++ylPBy}l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fLU8nUduwOtIgvNIvpyber9I3OE9buzInwKmyNuf///@6Bf@NTQA)

Outputs the whole list. Warning: highly inefficient; the `2231` input case has been running for 35+ minutes on my laptop and still hasn't finished.

#### Explanation

```
                               a is cmdline arg, l is [] (implicit)
Fn,a+1{                    }   For each n in range(a+1):
       Y0                       Yank 0 into y
         W                      While...
          yNl|                  y is in l, or...
              _Ny               lambda function: arg is in y
                 MSn            mapped to digits of n and result list summed
                                (i.e., any digit of n is in y):
                    ++y          Increment y
                       lPBy     Once we have a y that meets the criteria, push it to
                                the back of l
                            l  Output l (formatted with -p flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Visual Basic .NET (.NET 4.5)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>260</s> 259 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```vb
Function A(n)
Dim p=New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Long),j="0",g=0
For i=0To n
j=0
While 1
If Not p.Contains(j)Then
g=1
For Each c In i.ToString
If j.Contains(c)Then g=0
Next
If g Then Exit While
End If
j+=1
End While
p.Add(j)
Next
A=p(n)
End Function
```

Loops through, generating previous terms in the sequence to then compare later. Then iterates the number as a string looking for matches.

Abuses VB.NET's typing system. For example, `j` is a string, but adding one converts to an integer for me. Integers are converted to Booleans where `0` is `False` and the rest are `True`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFPb4MwDMXv@RRWLyNaF8H@HDmgjk6VWiqtSDu3YKgRdRiErfv0LEk17dKe4jzn/Z6tfB0eCt3jtNHl2CJsIvFKJyDYD7DWXMMd9Pg5Uo8lVLoHlaU5LLbv6RxYmyu9Z/UyLUcuDGmGJGDpeV2c4TfsfgaDJ7XQbYv@waDekLGnQq1pMMG28ply3sSzcDav41AsLZfiMNfAorH3jyPZKSOxqiCz@Z2FsdkTD0EjIT8iizqOvCvdF0coYMVAKtc70xPXztb8WwrpHOByMjwb1609BNIzGfBZIuUSVpVo7i3X1Re1U0lZ2syLMYk7t6lr/@0@7cYDbGxMIIWwiYNuUX30ZHBNjEEShFJe1R9v6E839OgmyJH8THYUf17@ePoF)

Comment: I never programmed in Visual Basic, but it seems you can remove the space at `If Not p.Contains(j)Then` same like you did at `If j.Contains(c)Then g=0` below. Also, `If Not p.Contains(j)Then \n g=1 \n For Each c In i.ToString \n If j.Contains(c)Then g=0 \n Next \n If g Then Exit While \n End If` can be shortened by removing `g` and using `Exit While` directly in the for-loop: `If Not p.Contains(j)Then \n For Each c In i.ToString \n If j.Contains(c)Then Exit While \n Next \n End If`, which will become [**241 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y8t6zc7n) by the looks of it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Definitely can remove the space to make it `Contains(c)Then`, I just missed it. I like what you're thinking, but I'm using `g` as a sentinel to see if the string contains the number or not. Your link gives the wrong answers, but I'll see if I can rework some of the inner logic along what you're thinking.

Comment: Ah oops.. It indeed fails.. Now it's only outputting the input. My bad. Shouldn't make these comments when it's evening and I'm tired from work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>[Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147435/53748) beats Jelly. Go Mr. Xcoder!</sup>

```
Df⁹LD¤ȯeṆ
0ç1#ɓ;
1Ç¡
```

A full program taking input from STDIN and outputting in the list format option using Jelly's list representation*. Uses the standard 0 based indexing.

* single element lists have no surrounding `[]`, so `0` outputs `1`, while `1` outputs `[1, 0]` etc.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//RGbigblMRMKkyK9l4bmGCjDDpzEjyZM7CjHDh8Kh//8xMg)**

#### How?

```
Df⁹LD¤ȯeṆ - Link 1, can append n to current? n, number; current, list
D         - convert n to decimal list
     ¤    - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  ⁹       -   chain's right argument, current
   L      -   length
    D     -   convert to a decimal list
 f        - filter discard from left if not in right
       e  - n exists in current?
      ȯ   - left logical OR right (empty lists are falsey)
        Ṇ - logical NOT

0ç1#ɓ; - Link 2, append next number: current, List
   #   - n find (count up finding first n matches):
  1    - ...finding: 1 match
0      - ...stating at: n=0
 ç     - ...doing: the last link as a dyad (left=n, right=current)
    ɓ  - new swapped-arg-dyadic chain (left = current, right = list of the found n)
     ; - concatenate

1Ç¡ - Main link: no arguments
1   - initialise the return value to 1
  ¡ - repeat input() times:
 Ç  -   last link (2) as a monad
    - implicit print
```